# Jenkins CLI Authentication

Tags: authentication, ssh, jenkins, command-line-interface, ssh-keys

I am trying to run groovysh on my Jenkins from the cli, using the following command:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s <Jenkins URL> -i JenkinsPrivateKey.ppk groovysh
```

I generated this private key file using PuttyGen, and pasted the public key into the SHH Public Keys box on the /me/configure page of the Jenkins.  It's not that the key doesn't work - it seems like it's not authenticating at all.  When I run who-am-i using the cli:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s <Jenkins URL> -i JenkinsPrivateKey.ppk who-am-i
```

It gives me a response of:

```
Authenticated as: anonymous
```

What am I missing here?  I thought if the authentication failed it would at least display an error message of some kind.  Is there any way to verify that the private key actually works?

Edit: After some experimentation, it seems that authentication via the CLI does fail silently - I put a bogus public key in my profile configuration, and I still saw no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to convert your putty keys to openssh format for them to work properly with the key.

See https://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Customer%2BProvided%2BSlaves%2BWindows

"Back to Putty Key Generator, use Conversions > Export OpenSSH key to save the private key to a file."

If that works, feel free to edit [the Jenkins CLI wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI)!

Comment: Thanks very much!  I'd like to add it to the wiki page as well.  Is it okay to link to the tutorial?

Comment: The tutorial is from cloudbees and relates to other features as well. I would prefer the Jenkins wiki to be self contained with regard to that information.