# Jenkins CLI authentication - Getting java.io.EOFException

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I've checked several threads regarding CLI access:

- [Jenkins CLI Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199355/jenkins-cli-authentication)
- [Using the jenkins CLI (on fedora 23)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105301/using-the-jenkins-cli-on-fedora-23)
- [Jenkins CLI connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502076/jenkins-cli-connection-refused)

And unfortunately it's not my case.

I'm trying to run the following command:

```
java.exe -jar jenkins-cli.jar -i C:\Users\myuser\.ssh\id_rsa -s http://MasterJenkins:port/ list-jobs All
```

And I'm getting the following execption:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readBoolean(DataInputStream.java:244)
    at hudson.cli.Connection.readBoolean(Connection.java:93)
    at hudson.cli.CLI.authenticate(CLI.java:565)
    at hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:476)
    at hudson.cli.CLI.main(CLI.java:387)
```

Going to : http://MasterJenkins:port/me/configure I made sure that the "SSH Public Keys" section is the same key I have in my public key. I was a month abroad, before leaving it worked, now it doesn't and my team member swears nothing changed in the system.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue last week with my own ssh private/public key.

I fixed it by

Generating a new public/private key combination using ssh-keygen

bash-4.1$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/users/xxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa): JenkinsCLI
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in JenkinsCLI.
Your public key has been saved in JenkinsCLI.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
f6:4c:be:fc:cb:cd:d3:ee:8c:80:26:a2:57:df:67:14 xxxxx@eeeee
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+

- Private file

Copy and paste the content of JenkinsCLI in your .private file

- Public file
  log into Jenkins>Click your Login id dropdown>Configure>SSH Public Keys

copy and paste the content of JenkinsCLI.pub file into SSH Public Keys text area
[image]

You should be able to authenticate.